# Cambiar imagen de fondo SVG en código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

He encontrado un código JS para usar en una web en el que caen diferentes copos de nieve.

Es el tradicional código que se usa en Navidad en las páginas web.

Como tengo un sitio musical se me ocurrió la idea de cambiar la imagen de los copos de nieve por notas musicales y de esa forma lo uso todo el año.

Cada copo de nieve está asociado a un extenso código SVG/XML que la verdad no se como se crea.

Cada tipo de copo está en un `background-image` diferente.

Les comparto la parte del código donde se encuentran las 5 imágenes diferentes de copos de nieve (`.snowflake__inner_type_0` a `.snowflake__inner_type_5`) y luego al final la URL para que puedan descargar/ver el código JS completo, no lo puedo publicar aquí porque supera los 300000 caracteres.

CODIGO DE IMAGENES SVG DE COPOS de NIEVE a CAMBIAR POR NOTA MUSICAL:

```
, p = ".snowflake__inner_type_0:before{background-image:url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='36.283' height='36.283'%3E%3Cpath d='M35.531 17.391h-3.09l.845-1.464a.748.748 0 10-1.297-.75l-1.276 2.214H28.61l2.515-4.354a.751.751 0 00-.272-1.024.75.75 0 00-1.024.274l-2.948 5.104h-2.023a6.751 6.751 0 00-2.713-4.684l1.019-1.76 5.896-.002a.75.75 0 000-1.5l-5.029.002 1.051-1.82 2.557.002a.75.75 0 000-1.5l-1.689-.002 1.545-2.676a.75.75 0 10-1.302-.75l-1.547 2.676-.844-1.463a.749.749 0 10-1.297.75l1.278 2.213-1.051 1.818-2.514-4.354a.75.75 0 00-1.298.75l2.946 5.104-1.016 1.758a6.692 6.692 0 00-2.706-.57 6.74 6.74 0 00-2.707.568l-1.013-1.754 2.946-5.105a.75.75 0 00-1.298-.75L13.56 8.697l-1.05-1.818 1.278-2.217a.749.749 0 00-1.298-.75l-.845 1.465-1.551-2.678a.75.75 0 00-1.024-.273.748.748 0 00-.274 1.023l1.545 2.678H8.652a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.556l1.05 1.818H7.231a.75.75 0 000 1.5h5.894l1.017 1.762a6.755 6.755 0 00-2.712 4.684H9.406l-2.95-5.104a.75.75 0 10-1.299.75l2.516 4.354H5.569l-1.277-2.213a.75.75 0 00-1.298.75l.845 1.463H.75a.75.75 0 000 1.5h3.09l-.845 1.465a.747.747 0 00.275 1.022.75.75 0 00.374.103.75.75 0 00.65-.375l1.277-2.215h2.103l-2.516 4.354a.75.75 0 001.299.75l2.949-5.104h2.024a6.761 6.761 0 002.712 4.685l-1.017 1.762H7.232a.75.75 0 000 1.5h5.026l-1.05 1.818H8.651a.75.75 0 000 1.5h1.69l-1.545 2.676a.75.75 0 001.299.75l1.546-2.676.846 1.465a.755.755 0 00.65.375.737.737 0 00.375-.103.747.747 0 00.274-1.022l-1.279-2.215 1.05-1.82 2.515 4.354a.75.75 0 001.299-.75l-2.947-5.104 1.013-1.756a6.72 6.72 0 005.415 0l1.014 1.756-2.947 5.104a.75.75 0 001.298.75l2.515-4.354 1.053 1.82-1.277 2.213a.75.75 0 001.298.75l.844-1.463 1.545 2.678c.141.24.393.375.65.375a.75.75 0 00.649-1.125l-1.548-2.678h1.689a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.557l-1.051-1.82 5.029.002a.75.75 0 000-1.5l-5.896-.002-1.019-1.76a6.75 6.75 0 002.711-4.685h2.023l2.947 5.104a.753.753 0 001.025.273.749.749 0 00.272-1.023l-2.515-4.354h2.104l1.279 2.215a.75.75 0 00.649.375c.127 0 .256-.03.375-.103a.748.748 0 00.273-1.022l-.848-1.465h3.092a.75.75 0 00.003-1.5zm-12.136.75c0 .257-.041.502-.076.75a5.223 5.223 0 01-1.943 3.358 5.242 5.242 0 01-1.291.766 5.224 5.224 0 01-1.949.384 5.157 5.157 0 01-3.239-1.15 5.22 5.22 0 01-1.943-3.358c-.036-.247-.076-.493-.076-.75s.04-.503.076-.75a5.22 5.22 0 011.944-3.359c.393-.312.82-.576 1.291-.765a5.219 5.219 0 011.948-.384c.69 0 1.344.142 1.948.384.471.188.898.454 1.291.765a5.222 5.222 0 011.943 3.359c.035.247.076.493.076.75z' fill='{color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")}.snowflake__inner_type_1:before{background-image:url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='32.813' height='32.813'%3E%3Cpath d='M29.106 24.424a.781.781 0 01-.781.781h-3.119v3.119a.782.782 0 01-1.562 0v-4.682h4.682c.43.001.78.351.78.782zM4.673 9.352h4.682V4.671a.781.781 0 00-1.563 0V7.79H4.673a.781.781 0 000 1.562zM3.708 24.24c0 .431.35.781.781.781H7.61v3.12a.78.78 0 101.562 0v-4.683H4.489a.782.782 0 00-.781.782zM28.923 8.39a.78.78 0 00-.781-.781h-3.121V4.488a.781.781 0 00-1.562 0v4.684h4.684a.783.783 0 00.78-.782zm3.889 8.017c0 .431-.35.781-.781.781h-3.426l1.876 1.873a.784.784 0 010 1.107.791.791 0 01-.554.228.773.773 0 01-.55-.228l-2.979-2.98h-2.995a6.995 6.995 0 01-1.728 3.875h5.609a.781.781 0 010 1.562h-4.666v4.667a.782.782 0 01-1.562 0v-5.61a7 7 0 01-3.866 1.719v2.995l2.978 2.98c.306.305.306.8 0 1.104a.78.78 0 01-1.104 0l-1.874-1.876v3.427a.781.781 0 01-1.562 0v-3.427l-1.875 1.876a.78.78 0 11-1.105-1.104l2.979-2.98v-2.995a7.016 7.016 0 01-3.865-1.717v5.608a.781.781 0 01-1.562 0v-4.667H5.535a.781.781 0 010-1.562h5.607a7.022 7.022 0 01-1.728-3.875H6.417l-2.979 2.979a.784.784 0 01-1.104 0 .781.781 0 010-1.106l1.874-1.873H.782a.78.78 0 11-.001-1.563h3.426L2.333 13.75a.783.783 0 011.105-1.106l2.979 2.979h2.995a6.996 6.996 0 011.72-3.866H5.533a.781.781 0 010-1.562h4.666V5.528a.781.781 0 011.562 0v5.599a6.995 6.995 0 013.865-1.717V6.415l-2.978-2.979a.782.782 0 011.105-1.105l1.874 1.875V.781a.78.78 0 111.562 0v3.426l1.875-1.875a.777.777 0 011.104 0 .78.78 0 010 1.105l-2.978 2.98v2.996a7.021 7.021 0 013.866 1.718V5.532a.78.78 0 111.562 0v4.666h4.666a.78.78 0 110 1.562h-5.599a7 7 0 011.718 3.866h2.995l2.979-2.979a.783.783 0 011.106 1.106l-1.876 1.874h3.427a.777.777 0 01.778.78zm-11.006-.782a5.457 5.457 0 00-4.618-4.617c-.257-.037-.514-.079-.781-.079-.268 0-.524.042-.781.079a5.458 5.458 0 00-4.618 4.617c-.038.257-.079.514-.079.781s.041.522.079.781a5.455 5.455 0 004.618 4.616c.257.036.514.079.781.079s.524-.043.781-.079a5.457 5.457 0 004.618-4.616c.037-.259.079-.515.079-.781s-.043-.524-.079-.781z' fill='{color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")}.snowflake__inner_type_2:before{background-image:url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='35.79' height='35.79'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.161 22.223l.026-.047.865.5-.026.047a.503.503 0 01-.434.25c-.019 0-.034-.013-.053-.016l-.355-.205a.493.493 0 01-.023-.529zM9.969 8.988l2.785.001 1.393-2.414a.502.502 0 00-.869-.499l-1.103 1.913-2.208-.001a.5.5 0 10.002 1zm15.854 17.813h-2.785l-1.393 2.411a.499.499 0 00.436.75c.172 0 .34-.09.434-.25l1.104-1.911h2.207c.274 0 .5-.224.5-.5a.505.505 0 00-.503-.5zM23.038 8.99h2.785a.5.5 0 000-1h-2.207l-1.105-1.913a.5.5 0 00-.868.5l1.395 2.413zM12.754 26.801H9.967a.5.5 0 000 1h2.209l1.105 1.912a.496.496 0 00.682.184.5.5 0 00.184-.684l-1.393-2.412zm-7.218-6.309a.502.502 0 00.685-.184l1.391-2.413-1.394-2.413a.5.5 0 00-.867.5l1.104 1.913-1.104 1.913a.5.5 0 00.185.684zM30.254 15.3a.505.505 0 00-.685.183l-1.392 2.412 1.395 2.414a.501.501 0 00.867-.5l-1.104-1.914 1.104-1.912a.5.5 0 00-.185-.683zm3.138 11.542a.501.501 0 01-.683.184l-.98-.565-2.137 1.231a.516.516 0 01-.5 0l-2.385-1.377a.502.502 0 01-.25-.433v-.854h-4.441l-2.225 3.852.736.428c.154.088.25.254.25.432l.001 2.755a.5.5 0 01-.25.433l-2.133 1.229v1.136c0 .274-.225.5-.5.5s-.5-.226-.5-.5v-1.136l-2.136-1.23a.5.5 0 01-.25-.433l.001-2.755c0-.178.096-.344.25-.432l.738-.427-2.224-3.849H9.332l.002.851a.505.505 0 01-.25.435l-2.387 1.377a.5.5 0 01-.5 0L4.06 26.46l-.982.567a.5.5 0 01-.5-.867l.982-.567.001-2.465c0-.179.097-.344.25-.434l2.388-1.377a.497.497 0 01.5 0l.736.426 2.221-3.848-2.222-3.849-.737.426a.51.51 0 01-.5 0l-2.386-1.377a.5.5 0 01-.25-.434l.002-2.464-.983-.567a.501.501 0 01-.184-.683.502.502 0 01.684-.183l.983.568 2.134-1.233a.5.5 0 01.5 0l2.385 1.379c.156.089.25.255.25.433v.85h4.443l2.223-3.846-.74-.427a.501.501 0 01-.25-.434l.002-2.755c0-.178.096-.343.25-.433l2.135-1.233V.5a.5.5 0 011 0v1.135l2.134 1.231c.154.089.25.254.25.434l-.002 2.755a.503.503 0 01-.25.433l-.733.425 2.224 3.849h4.44l-.002-.851c0-.179.096-.344.25-.434l2.388-1.378a.502.502 0 01.5 0l2.136 1.233.982-.568a.5.5 0 11.5.866l-.983.568v2.464a.503.503 0 01-.25.433l-2.388 1.378a.5.5 0 01-.5 0l-.735-.426-2.222 3.849 2.223 3.849.734-.425a.506.506 0 01.5 0l2.389 1.375c.154.09.25.255.25.435l-.002 2.462.982.568c.24.137.321.444.182.682zm-2.165-1.828l.001-1.597-1.888-1.087-.734.424-.348.201-.301.173-.5.289v2.179l1.885 1.088 1.386-.802.498-.286.001-.582zm-3.736-11.467l-.531-.307-2.283 1.318-2.443 3.337 2.442 3.337 2.283 1.316.531-.306-2.514-4.348 2.515-4.347zm-7.712 16.478l-.762-.438-.339-.194-.283-.166-.5-.289-.5.289-.279.162-.349.2-.757.437-.001 2.177 1.386.797.501.289.499-.287 1.386-.798-.002-2.179zM16.008 5.767l.736.425.371.214.279.16.5.288.5-.289.281-.163.367-.212.732-.424.002-2.178-1.381-.797-.502-.289-.498.287-1.385.8-.002 2.178zm6.52 14.227l-1.535-2.099 1.535-2.098.732-1-1.232.134-2.585.281-1.048-2.379-.5-1.133-.5 1.134-1.049 2.379-2.585-.281-1.232-.134.732 1 1.536 2.097-1.536 2.098-.732 1 1.232-.134 2.585-.281 1.049 2.379.5 1.134.5-1.134 1.048-2.379 2.585.281 1.232.134-.732-.999zm8.2-10.084l-1.386-.8-1.887 1.089v1.279l.002.32v.577l.5.289.28.163.367.213.732.424 1.888-1.089v-2.178l-.496-.287zM18.927 7.413l-.532.307v2.637l1.667 3.784 4.111-.447 2.283-1.317-.002-.613h-5.02l-2.507-4.351zm-9.594 4.348v.614l2.283 1.318 4.111.447 1.668-3.785V7.719l-.531-.306-2.509 4.347-5.022.001zm-2.15 1.279l.37-.213.279-.162.5-.289V10.2L6.446 9.11l-1.384.8-.499.289v.578l-.002 1.599 1.885 1.088.737-.424zm1.119 9.205l.53.306 2.281-1.316 2.443-3.339-2.442-3.337-2.281-1.317-.531.307 2.511 4.348-2.511 4.348zm-1.115-.069l-.026.047a.493.493 0 00.023.529l-.734-.424-1.887 1.089-.001 1.599v.578l.5.288 1.386.8 1.887-1.088v-1.278l-.002-.321v-.577l-.5-.289-.293-.169c.02.002.035.017.055.017a.5.5 0 00.433-.25l.026-.047-.867-.504zm9.679 6.202l.529-.306v-2.637l-1.668-3.785-4.111.447-2.283 1.316.002.611 5.021.002 2.51 4.352zm9.591-4.349v-.612L24.174 22.1l-4.111-.447-1.667 3.783v2.639l.531.307 2.512-4.352h5.018v-.001z' fill='{color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")}.snowflake__inner_type_3:before{background-image:url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='32.815' height='32.815'%3E%3Cpath d='M4.581 23.55h4.681v4.681a.78.78 0 11-1.562 0v-3.118H4.581a.781.781 0 010-1.563zM29.016 8.481a.781.781 0 00-.781-.781h-3.119V4.582a.781.781 0 00-1.562 0v4.681h4.682c.429 0 .78-.35.78-.782zm-24.252.598l4.683-.001V4.395a.781.781 0 00-1.562 0v3.121l-3.121.001a.781.781 0 000 1.562zm23.655 14.287h-4.685l.002 4.684a.78.78 0 101.562 0l-.002-3.121h3.122a.781.781 0 00.001-1.563zm4.394-6.96a.78.78 0 01-.781.781h-3.426l1.876 1.875a.782.782 0 01-1.104 1.105l-2.979-2.979h-1.986L17.19 24.41v1.987l2.977 2.979a.781.781 0 01-1.103 1.106l-1.874-1.875v3.426a.78.78 0 11-1.562 0v-3.426l-1.875 1.875a.782.782 0 01-1.105-1.105l2.978-2.979V24.41l-7.219-7.22H6.418l-2.98 2.98a.777.777 0 01-1.103 0 .781.781 0 010-1.106L4.21 17.19H.783a.78.78 0 110-1.562h3.426l-1.876-1.875a.782.782 0 111.106-1.105l2.979 2.979h1.989l7.219-7.218v-1.99L12.648 3.44a.782.782 0 111.106-1.105l1.874 1.874V.781a.782.782 0 011.563 0v3.426l1.875-1.875a.783.783 0 011.106 1.105l-2.979 2.979v1.99l7.216 7.218h1.992l2.979-2.979a.782.782 0 011.105 1.105l-1.876 1.874h3.427a.781.781 0 01.777.782zm-10.613.782l.778-.78-.781-.782-5.009-5.008-.781-.781-.781.781-5.01 5.008-.781.781.781.781 5.01 5.011.782.781.78-.779 5.012-5.013zm5.863 4.646a.782.782 0 00-.781-.781h-6.229v6.228a.78.78 0 101.562 0v-4.665h4.666a.782.782 0 00.782-.782zm-.001-10.855a.782.782 0 00-.781-.781h-4.664V5.532a.782.782 0 00-1.562 0v6.228h6.227a.78.78 0 00.78-.781zm-23.318 0c0 .432.35.781.781.781h6.228V5.532a.781.781 0 00-1.562 0v4.666H5.525a.781.781 0 00-.781.781zm.002 10.855c0 .432.35.781.781.781h4.664v4.665a.78.78 0 101.562 0v-6.228H5.527a.783.783 0 00-.781.782z' fill='{color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")}.snowflake__inner_type_4:before{background-image:url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='37.794' height='37.794'%3E%3Cpath d='M30.638 17.313l-.914 1.584.915 1.585a.78.78 0 11-1.352.78l-1.366-2.366 1.366-2.365a.782.782 0 011.067-.286c.372.215.5.692.284 1.068zM11.65 11.08l2.733.002 1.367-2.367a.78.78 0 00-1.352-.781l-.915 1.585-1.831-.002h-.001a.78.78 0 00-.001 1.563zm14.491 15.633h-2.733l-1.365 2.365a.78.78 0 101.352.78l.914-1.584h1.831a.781.781 0 00.001-1.561zm-4.1-17.998l1.367 2.367h2.733a.78.78 0 100-1.562h-1.833l-.915-1.585a.78.78 0 00-1.352.78zM15.75 29.08l-1.368-2.366h-2.733a.781.781 0 000 1.562h1.832l.917 1.585c.146.25.409.391.677.391a.779.779 0 00.675-1.172zm-8.313-7.531a.78.78 0 001.067-.284L9.87 18.9l-1.367-2.368a.781.781 0 00-1.351.781l.916 1.587-.914 1.584a.776.776 0 00.283 1.065zm27.827 6.798a.784.784 0 01-1.067.285l-.89-.515-2.096 1.209a.793.793 0 01-.391.105.762.762 0 01-.391-.105l-2.484-1.435a.78.78 0 01-.391-.676l-.002-2.417-2.408-1.392a7.714 7.714 0 01-5.467 3.168v2.773l2.093 1.208a.78.78 0 01.391.676l.001 2.868c0 .28-.149.537-.392.676l-2.093 1.205v1.032a.781.781 0 01-1.562 0V35.98l-2.095-1.207a.78.78 0 01-.391-.676l.001-2.868c0-.28.15-.537.391-.676l2.094-1.206v-2.773a7.718 7.718 0 01-5.468-3.168l-2.408 1.392.002 2.415c0 .281-.15.539-.391.676l-2.487 1.437a.785.785 0 01-.782 0l-2.095-1.209-.893.518a.782.782 0 01-.782-1.354l.893-.517.001-2.414a.78.78 0 01.391-.677l2.487-1.434a.774.774 0 01.781 0l2.093 1.208 2.407-1.39a7.655 7.655 0 010-6.317l-2.406-1.39-2.096 1.209a.772.772 0 01-.782 0l-2.485-1.434a.786.786 0 01-.391-.676l.002-2.416-.894-.517a.78.78 0 01-.285-1.066.788.788 0 011.07-.283l.893.514 2.093-1.208a.774.774 0 01.781 0L9.851 9.91c.24.14.391.398.391.675L10.24 13l2.408 1.392a7.712 7.712 0 015.468-3.167V8.45L16.02 7.242a.78.78 0 01-.391-.676l.002-2.87c0-.279.15-.538.391-.675l2.094-1.208V.781a.781.781 0 011.562 0v1.032l2.093 1.206a.785.785 0 01.391.677l-.002 2.87c0 .28-.149.536-.391.674l-2.091 1.208v2.772a7.708 7.708 0 015.467 3.167l2.409-1.392-.002-2.416c0-.28.149-.539.391-.676l2.487-1.436c.24-.14.539-.14.781 0l2.095 1.208.894-.514a.78.78 0 11.781 1.352l-.894.516v2.417c0 .279-.15.538-.391.675l-2.487 1.436a.785.785 0 01-.782 0l-2.092-1.209-2.408 1.39c.436.967.684 2.032.684 3.158a7.65 7.65 0 01-.684 3.158l2.408 1.391 2.091-1.206a.782.782 0 01.78 0l2.488 1.432c.24.141.392.398.392.677l-.002 2.414.893.517a.783.783 0 01.287 1.068zm-6.147-16.251l.001.9.78.453.921.531 1.706-.982v-1.965l-.78-.451-.923-.533-1.707.983.002 1.064zm-20.443-.002l.002-1.063-1.706-.985-.922.535-.778.451-.001.902-.001 1.063 1.703.982.924-.533.779-.451v-.901zm0 13.604l-.001-.899-.781-.451-.919-.533-1.706.982-.001 1.064v.901l.781.451.923.533 1.707-.982-.003-1.066zm15.109-3.076c.315-.413.586-.864.789-1.351a6.121 6.121 0 000-4.748 6.175 6.175 0 00-.789-1.35 6.158 6.158 0 00-4.106-2.375 6.48 6.48 0 00-.781-.056c-.266 0-.525.022-.781.056a6.149 6.149 0 00-4.106 2.375 6.128 6.128 0 00-.789 1.35 6.104 6.104 0 00-.479 2.374 6.1 6.1 0 001.268 3.725 6.15 6.15 0 004.106 2.374c.256.031.516.056.781.056s.525-.022.781-.056a6.142 6.142 0 004.106-2.374zM17.19 6.113l.924.531.781.452.781-.452.919-.531.002-1.968-.921-.531-.784-.452-.779.451-.922.532-.001 1.968zm3.408 25.57l-.921-.532-.781-.452-.781.452-.922.532-.001 1.966.923.531.782.451.78-.449.922-.533-.001-1.966zm11.925-5.819l.001-1.063-1.707-.981-.919.529-.782.451v.901l.001 1.065 1.702.981.924-.533.778-.449.002-.901z' fill='{color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")}.snowflake__inner_type_5:before{background-image:url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='31.25' height='31.25'%3E%3Cpath d='M20.581 1.176l-3.914 3.915V0h1.041v2.576L19.845.439l.736.737zm-1.615 9.069l.351.217 6.623-6.625-.736-.737-6.048 6.051a7.141 7.141 0 00-1.449-.6v-.082l5.082-5.082-.737-.737-5.387 5.388v1.33l.402.093a6.213 6.213 0 011.899.784zm2.041 2.043c.368.585.63 1.224.786 1.893l.094.403h1.028l5.171-5.173-.736-.737-4.699 4.701a7.523 7.523 0 00-.549-1.28l6.048-6.05-.737-.735-6.622 6.625.216.353zm7.368 1.254l1.921-1.923-.736-.735-3.699 3.7h5.39v-1.042h-2.876zm1.185 6.826l.736-.736-1.923-1.923h2.877v-1.042h-5.389l3.699 3.701zm-6.915-2.498l4.705 4.707.736-.736-5.171-5.174h-1.03l-.096.4a6.24 6.24 0 01-.795 1.883l-.22.353 6.639 6.641.736-.736-6.061-6.062c.227-.414.414-.84.557-1.276zm-3.7 3.125a6.241 6.241 0 01-1.88.794l-.399.096v1.33l5.387 5.387.736-.736-5.082-5.082v-.089a7.322 7.322 0 001.434-.605l6.061 6.062.736-.736-6.641-6.641-.352.22zM16.667 31.25h1.041v-2.576l2.137 2.137.736-.737-3.914-3.914v5.09zm-5.26-.439l2.134-2.137v2.576h1.042v-5.093l-3.913 3.916.737.738zm.897-9.816l-.352-.222-6.642 6.641.736.736 6.062-6.062c.456.254.937.456 1.433.605v.089l-5.08 5.082.736.736 5.387-5.387v-1.33l-.4-.096a6.175 6.175 0 01-1.88-.792zm-2.046-2.047a6.315 6.315 0 01-.798-1.883l-.096-.4H8.335l-5.172 5.174.737.736 4.706-4.71c.145.441.329.865.556 1.276L3.1 25.202l.736.736 6.643-6.643-.221-.347zM0 16.667v1.042h2.876L.954 19.632l.736.736 3.698-3.701H0zm1.69-5.783l-.736.735 1.921 1.923H0v1.042h5.39l-3.7-3.7zm6.916 2.498L3.9 8.674l-.736.737 5.172 5.173h1.029l.096-.4a6.15 6.15 0 01.798-1.881l.222-.352L3.837 5.31l-.736.736 6.062 6.06a7.268 7.268 0 00-.557 1.276zm-.145-9.996l5.08 5.082v.088c-.497.15-.977.352-1.433.606L6.047 3.101l-.736.737 6.643 6.643.352-.222a6.223 6.223 0 011.88-.797l.4-.095v-1.33L9.2 2.649l-.739.737zm5.081-.81L11.408.439l-.736.737 3.913 3.917V0h-1.042v2.576zm-1.757 14.831a4.2 4.2 0 002.06 2.058l.739.338v-3.136h-3.138l.339.74zm0-3.562l-.337.738h3.135v-3.136l-.739.338a4.223 4.223 0 00-2.059 2.06zm7.679 3.561l.338-.739h-3.135v3.136l.738-.338a4.204 4.204 0 002.059-2.059zm0-3.561a4.198 4.198 0 00-2.059-2.06l-.738-.34v3.138h3.135l-.338-.738z' fill='{color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")}"
```

CODIGO COMPLETO ORIGINAL COMPRIMIDO: https://unpkg.com/magic-snowflakes/dist/snowflakes.min.js

CODIGO COMPLETO MAS AMIGABLE A LA VISTA: https://mega.nz/file/RUlAxIDa#7UTnVv4GVJJy5cmcbmX7cGI9n0fRLdGBI1EFwhSvEAo

Ya le hice la consulta al desarrollador (Denis Seleznev) en github pero no me ha respondido nada aún.

Para los que deseen usar el código original en su web sin configurar nada basta con editar el index HTML de esta forma:

```
<html>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/magic-snowflakes/dist/snowflakes.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Snowflakes();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparto la solución proporcionada por el desarrollador, la cual funciona correctamente.
En lugar de usar el código SVG puedo incluir una imagen en PNG o cualquier otro formato admitido por los navegadores.
Le hice una pequeña corrección a lo sugerido por el desarrollador para que se adaptara mejor al código original:

LINEA 174

```css
, p = ".snowflake__inner_type_0:before{background-image: url('./img/note0.png')}.snowflake__inner_type_1:before{background-image: url('./img/note1.png')}.snowflake__inner_type_2:before{background-image: url('./img/note2.png')}.snowflake__inner_type_3:before{background-image:  url('./img/note3.png')}.snowflake__inner_type_4:before{background-image:  url('./img/note4.png')}.snowflake__inner_type_5:before{background-image:  url('./img/note5.png')}"
```